# Transaction with more than one table in Propel2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions, propel2

In the documentation of Propel2 ORM (http://propelorm.org/documentation/05-transactions.html) there is an example how to wrap queries inside a transaction. The connection is made to a single database table "Account":

```
$con = Propel::getWriteConnection(AccountTableMap::DATABASE_NAME);
```

How can I get a global PDO connection object or a connection to 2 tables (e.g. "Account" and "Book")?

For example that's (in pseudocode) what I wish to have:

```
$con = Propel::getWriteConnection(AccountTableMap::DATABASE_NAME, 
                                  BookTableMap::DATABASE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you quote makes it fairly plain. Your mistake is thinking as you say in your question *The connection is made to a single database table "Account":*. No a connection is always to a whole database. Propel just provides a way of getting the connection handle that uses a table as a parameter, confusing I grant you.

You do

```
$con = Propel::getWriteConnection(AccountTableMap::DATABASE_NAME);
```

on any table, just to get the `$con` connection handle.

Transactions are controlled by the connection, not a statement. So once you have the connection object you can start a transaction, and the whole point of a transaction is you can change any number of tables within that transaction as a single unit of work (transaction).

So once you have the `$con` handle you start a transaction

```
$con->beginTransaction();
```

and any amendments you make between that statement and a

```
$con->commit();
```

OR

```
$con->rollback();
```

Will all be commited together or all be rolledback together.